# Increment a key value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, enumerate

I would like to add an id key to a list of dictionaries, where each id represents the enumerated nested dictionary.

**Current list of dictionaries:**

```
current_list_d = [{'id': 0, 'name': 'Paco', 'age': 18} #all id's are 0
                  {'id': 0, 'name': 'John', 'age': 20}
                  {'id': 0, 'name': 'Claire', 'age': 22}]
```

**Desired output:**

```
output_list_d = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Paco', 'age': 18} #id's are counted/enumerated
                  {'id': 2, 'name': 'John', 'age': 20}
                  {'id': 3, 'name': 'Claire', 'age': 22}]
```

My code:

```
for d in current_list_d:
    d["id"]+=1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a simple for loop with [`enumerate`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) and update in-place the `id` keys in the dictionaries:

```
for new_id, d in enumerate(current_list_d, start=1):
    d['id'] = new_id

current_list_d
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Paco', 'age': 18},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'John', 'age': 20},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'Claire', 'age': 22}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable.

```
id_val = 1
for dict in current_list_d :
    dict["id"] = id_val
    id_val+=1
```